# Iterable<model> to model

Tags: flutter, dart

I've got list of models

```
List<CategoryModel> categories = [CategoryModel(id:1), CategoryModel(id:2)]
```

and from that list of models I want to get one model with id equal to 1 so I use where clause but that return Iterable of that model.

```
CategoryModel category =
        categories.where((element) => element.id == 1)
```

How can I transfer it to model

Comment: Instance of model is exactly what you need

Comment: @JideGuru sorry I made a mistake... Let me rephrase that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `firstWhere`:

```
categories.firstWhere((element) => element.id == 1)
```